# Eclipse JDT resolve unknown kind from annotation IMemberValuePair

Tags: eclipse-jdt

I need to retrieve the value from an annotation such as this one that uses a string constant:

```
@Component(property = Constants.SERVICE_RANKING + ":Integer=10")
public class NyServiceImpl implements MyService {
```

But I am getting a kind of K_UNKNOWN and the doc says "the value is an expression that would need to be further analyzed to determine its kind". My question then is how do I perform this analysis? I could even manage to accept getting the plain source text value in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer looks basically OK, but let me suggest a way to avoid using the internal class `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Annotation` and its method `findNode()`:

```
ISourceRange range = annotation.getSourceRange();
ASTNode annNode = org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.NodeFinder.perform(cu, range);
```

From here on you should be safe, using DOM API throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Googling differently I found a way to resolve the expression. Still open to other suggestions if any. For those who might be interested, here is a snippet of code:

```
    if (valueKind == IMemberValuePair.K_UNKNOWN) {
    Annotation ann = (Annotation)annotation;
    CompilationUnit cu = getAST(ann.getCompilationUnit());
    ASTNode annNode = ann.findNode(cu);
    NormalAnnotation na = (NormalAnnotation)annNode;
    List<?> naValues = na.values();
    Optional<?> optMvp = naValues.stream()
            .filter(val-> ((MemberValuePair)val).getName().getIdentifier().equals(PROPERTY))
            .findAny();

    if (optMvp.isPresent()) {
        MemberValuePair pair = (MemberValuePair)optMvp.get();

        if (pair.getValue() instanceof ArrayInitializer) {
            ArrayInitializer ai = (ArrayInitializer)pair.getValue();
            for (Object exprObj : ai.expressions()) {
                Expression expr = (Expression)exprObj;
                String propValue = (String)expr.resolveConstantExpressionValue();
                if (propValue.startsWith(Constants.SERVICE_RANKING)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            Expression expr = pair.getValue();
            String propValue = (String)expr.resolveConstantExpressionValue();
            if (propValue.startsWith(Constants.SERVICE_RANKING)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }                   
    //report error
}

private CompilationUnit getAST(ICompilationUnit compUnit) {
    final ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8); 
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setSource(compUnit);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true); // we need bindings later on
    CompilationUnit unit = (CompilationUnit)parser.createAST(null);
    return unit;
}
```